# How to prove $f$ has a simple discontinuous at $x_0$? (picture)

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ except at $x_{0} \in (a, b)$, where $f$ has a discontinuity. Suppose further that $f(x)$ is rational for every $x \in [a, b]$. Prove that $f$ has a simple discontinuity at $x_{0}$.

Is there a hint which is $f$ is constant on the intervals $[a,x_0)$ and $(x_0,b]$ without solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image of an interval under a continuous real function is an interval. And the only intervals of the real line containing only rational numbers are singletons.

Therefore $f([a, x_0)) = \{f_a\}$, $f((x_0, b]) = \{f_b\}$ and $f(x_0) = y_0$ where $f_a, f_b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

That proves that $f$ has a simple discontinuity at $x_0$.

Comment: wow! thank you! I understand well!